# How to install POP OS without a USB drive or DVD

Tags: system-installation, pop-os

I Want To Install Linux On My laptop to Replace Windows 11. It is a Lenovo D330 2 in 1.

---

Processor

> Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz 1.10 GHz

Comment: Does your laptop not have a USB port?

Comment: Maybe a network install is possible. You will need another computer to act as a server. Or remove secondary storage, and plug into another device.

Comment: You can always write the installation iso to the drive as a bootable disc but would require erasing the file completely

Comment: yes it does⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 0):

While not POP_OS there is another Debian based distribution called [Q4OS](https://q4os.org/index.html) that has a 21 MB [Windows Installer](https://q4os.org/downloads1.html). Speaking from experience with my Windows 10 laptop I can tell you that it's possibly one of the easiest ways to get Linux running in a dual-boot environment. This way you can at least try it out before committing to it full time.

Once you have the installer [downloaded](https://q4os.org/downloads1.html) take a moment to learn how to reach the bootloader for your particular laptop. It might be <kbd>Esc</kbd> or one of the <kbd>F*nn*</kbd> keys.

Next, be sure you're connected to the internet. Then just run the Q4OS installer as if installing a typical Windows application. It will take care of all the technical details of setting up Q4OS alongside Windows.

I can't recall how much space you'll need but believe it gives the choice to set aside 5, 20 or more GB for the entire Q4OS installation.

Once it's finished you'll reboot the computer and enter the boot selection screen. Use the arrow keys to select the Q4OS installation and the Welcome tutorial will take over from there.